# iOS Launchscreen is not being displayed in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, launchimage

I don't know what happened but since some days ago the LaunchScreen is not being displayed. Check the following:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: You are defining LaunchImage and LaunchScreen.storyboard at the same time? Which one that you want to use?

Comment: delete `XSLaunchImageAssets` key string ,use LaunchScreen only. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/launch-screens/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you want to use `LaunchImage Assets` for your `LaunchScreen`. You are setting `Source` & `LaunchScreen`, both, at the same time.

If you want to use `LaunchImage Assets`, Delete the content inside the `Launch Screen` in `info.plist` as below:

[image]

`Launch Screen` uses the `LaunchScreen.storyboard` single file to use across the devices (iPhone/iPads).
While Assets `Source` uses the Image catalogs, to set specific Launch Image for some specific device of resolution.

You have to use both of this options as an alternatives.